# how to indent strictly in multiples of tabstop (e.g. 4)

Tags: indentation

Demonstration of the problem:

```
# starting point:
function hello_world {
    _somecommand_ parameter '
    | <--- point/cursor is here on step one
    '
}

# the next step (I take issue with):
function hello_world {
    _somecommand_ parameter '
    TAB           | <--- point/cursor is now here on step two
                         alligned right under the beginning of `awk`.
                         that's not a multiple of four and it "skipped" several multiples.
    '
}

# the next step (what I actually wanted to happen):
function hello_world {
    _somecommand_ parameter '
    TAB | <--- I want the cursor to be strictly just 4 spaces to the right of TAB
    '
}

# Legend:
# `|`   == the cursor/point
# `TAB` == press the TAB key at that position
```

There seems to be some mode I'm not aware of that auto-aligns words vertically in some situations, where in fact I'd like my indentation to be predictable and strictly in multiples of whatever tabstop I have defined (I prefer four, and with no "skips").

How to achieve this?

Comment: What's the value of variable `tab-width` in the buffer in question? This is a buffer-local variable. Do you see the same thing if you start Emacs using `emacs -Q` (no init file)? If not, bisect your init file to find the culprit.

Comment: What is key `TAB` bound to in the mode you're in? In programming modes it's typically bound to a command that indents according to the style defined for that mode - it doesn't indent a fixed `tab-width` amount.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dumb indentation](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/3060/dumb-indentation)

Comment: See also https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/31094, as another possible duplicate, depending on what you're doing and what you want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```lisp
;;; some spacemacs default I don't like and I
;;; don't know from which layer it comes from:
;; (setq indent-line-function 'smie-indent-line)

;;; instead use this for achieve "predictable indents":
(setq indent-line-function 'insert-tab)

;;; or
;; (setq-local indent-line-function 'insert-tab)
```

I figured out that my `indent-line-function` was some special function I don't recognize.

Setting it to `insert-tab` does exactly what I was looking for.

Thanks for the links to the other questions @Drew.